# What type of product? $\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}:= \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T - \mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, exterior-algebra, cross-product, outer-product

What do you know about the names and properties of the products of the following definitions?
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{a,b}\in\mathbb{R}^N, \mathbf{C}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}\\
&\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}:= \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T - \mathbf{b}\mathbf{a}^T
\end{align}
I found some propeties.
\begin{align}
& \mathbf{b} \circledast \mathbf{a} = - \mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b})^T\\
& \mathbf{a} \circledast (\beta \mathbf{b} + \gamma \mathbf{c}) = \beta (\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}) + \gamma (\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{c})
\end{align}
In addition, let $\mathbf{x} = \alpha \mathbf{a} + \beta \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{A} = [\mathbf{a}~\mathbf{b}] \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 2}$,
\begin{align}
& \mathbf{x}^T (\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}) \mathbf{x} = 0 \\
&\|(\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}) \mathbf{x}\|_2 = \sqrt{\det \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}} \| \mathbf{x} \|_2 
\end{align}
therefore, $\mathbf{R} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}}}\mathbf{a} \circledast \mathbf{b}$ is $\pi/2$ [rad] rotation matrix for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{range}\mathbf{A}$.

Do you know the name of this product?
Can you find any other properties about this product?

---

We now understand that this product is closely related to the wedge product.

How can I make this product more interesting as wedge product?
For example, the wedge product can be stacked many times.
\begin{align}
a \wedge b \wedge c
\end{align}
But my product cannot be stacked.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator 
in ring theory

Comment: It's not exactly a commutator because the binary operation given by the OP yields a matrix, so it lives in a different group than the original vectors.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about commutator.

Comment: It’s probably worth pointing out that $a\circledast b=0$ iff $a$ and $b$ are parallel. Which is of course well known for wedge products.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the representation of the wedge product $a\wedge b$ as a skew-symmetric matrix. (Note that $\mathbf C$ is skew-symmetric.) If $a=\sum a_ie_i$ and $b=\sum b_je_j$, then $a\wedge b = \sum\limits_{i<j} (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)e_i\wedge e_j$.
(You might read more about exterior algebra.)

Comment: I found the relationship between my product and the wedge product interesting.
I have updated the question.

Comment: It seems that this makes your construction more limited and, indeed, less interesting.